# How we can use the parathread feature on polkadot chain?

Tags: parathread

I have read about the parathread feature on polkadot. by which if we have minimal load on chain so we can go with parathread instead of parachain.
references i read: https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-parathreads
https://medium.com/polkadot-network/parathreads-pay-as-you-go-parachains-7440d23dde06

But i have not found the guide or process how we can do it.
can you please share some resource about the process to live the parathread?

how the flow will work to finalize transactions as a parathread?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parathreads are not yet live, but the work has started: https://forum.polkadot.network/t/on-demand-parachains/2208